# Break out of a begin/end block early

Tags: ruby, memoization

I want a way to exit a begin/end block while still assigning the variable that its result is assigned to.

```
def foo
  @foo ||= begin
    puts "running"

    return "leaving early" if true # would be some sort of calculation

    # Other calculations
  end
end
```

What I hope to happen

```
> foo
running
=> leaving early
> foo
=> leaving early
```

What actually happens

```
> foo
running
=> leaving early
> foo
running
=> leaving early
```

The code doesn't work because `return` exits the entire method without setting `@foo`. Using `break` or `next` only work in loops. Does anything work within a begin block the way I'm thinking?

Current ways I can do it but was hoping to avoid:

- Assigning the variable within the begin block and returning
- Putting the remaining portion of the begin block in an if statement
- Performing the calculation before the begin block

There seem to be a lot of related questions about breaking out of blocks but I couldn't find one that answers this specific version (maybe because it's not possible).

Comment: I don't understand why you didn't get a *void value exception* `SyntaxError`. That occurs when the parser is unable to determine how a value would be assigned, here caused by the `return` statement (even if it had been `return "leaving early" if false`). That's what I got with v2.6.1. What Ruby version are you using?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good catch. Looks like it works if you have something after the return, like a `puts "finished"` or just some value to return

Comment: Yes, but it's still weird.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you're going to save yourself a whole heck of a lot of strife if you just put all that logic into its own method:

```
def foo
  @foo ||= compute_foo
end

def compute_foo
  puts "running"

  return "leaving early" if true # would be some sort of calculation

  # Other calculations
end
```

This decouples the computation from the memoization, making it easier to test and reason about, and it's a fairly common design pattern in Ruby and other languages.

Of course, there are ways of doing what you're asking. The most obvious solution being an immediately-invoked anonymous proc:

```
def foo
  @foo ||= (proc do
    puts "running"

    next "leaving early" if true # would be some sort of calculation

    # Other calculations
  end)[] # or .call or .()
end
```

But you certainly wouldn't be doing yourself or any future maintainers of this code any favors.

Comment: That's some great insight. Using another method makes a lot of sense here, but having the option to use a anonymous proc is an interesting possibility

Comment: This is good advice but it doesn't answer the question: "Does anything work within a begin block the way I'm thinking?".

Comment: @CarySwoveland I believe I've answered it implicitly, but here's the answer explicitly: No, not to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: The OP has answered that question in the affirmative in a recent comment on the question, though we agree it's not good coding practice

Comment: @CarySwoveland That solves the SyntaxError, but it doesn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: True. I must work harder on my bad habits, that one failing to consider questions in their entirety.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loop do ... end` construction instead of `begin ... end`
In this case you can use `break <value>` to return value from the block.

```
def foo
  @foo ||= loop do
     puts "running"

     break "leaving early" if true # would be some sort of calculation

     # Other calculations
     break "leaving at the end"
  end
end
```

This will give you result you expected:

```
> foo
running
=> leaving early
> foo
=> leaving early
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it inside a `begin`/`end` block,

Syntax errors were raised on both `next` and `break`.

Other than `loop`, another alternative is `tap`, it returns it's (mutated) self.

 Like `begin`, `break` also breaks `tap`, but `next` won't.

```
> true_bar = Bar.new
=> #<Bar:0x00007f9dfdadcb20 @is_really_true=true>
> 
> true_bar.foo
running
=> "leaving early"
> 
> true_bar.foo
=> "leaving early"
> 
> false_bar = Bar.new.not_really
=> #<Bar:0x00007f9dfdce9300 @is_really_true=false>
> 
> false_bar.foo
running
run more
=> "leave at the end"
> 
> false_bar.foo
=> "leave at the end"
```

source:

```rb
class Bar
  def initialize; @really_true = true; end

  def foo
    @foo ||= "".tap do |respond|
      puts 'running'

      next respond << 'leaving early' if really_true?

      respond << 'leave at the end'
      puts 'run more'
    end
  end

  def not_really
    self.tap { @really_true = false }
  end

  def really_true?; @really_true; end
end
```